# error LNK2001 Visual C++

Tags: c++

I compile this code:

```
class TextBox
{
public: 
struct Caret {int x; int y; int index;};
    static Caret caret;
    // more code...
}
```

and I got this error

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct TextBox::Caret TextBox::caret" (?caret@TextBox@@2UCaret@1@A)
```

What is my mistake

Comment: look for "static data members must be defined outside the class in a single translation unit"

Comment: You need to initialise static variable in the program outside the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate `caret`; add this in the source file:

```
TextBox::Caret TextBox::caret;
```